# Intercept Blackberry Calls

Tags: java, c++, blackberry, blackberry-10

How can i intercept blackberry calls audio and amplify the audio before the audio is sent out?

My blackberry z30 running on the latest bb10 OS has had an issue of low voice calls. Everyone complains that they cant hear me when on call. However, when am recording audio say on whatsapp calls or video recording, the audio is crystal clear, meaning somehow blackberry suppresses my call audio only.

I dont want to throw away the phone without putting up a good fight, programmatically.  I would like to try to "intercept" the audio on calls, amplify the sound then send out the voice, much louder. Any possibility of achieving this? I am good in Java and c++ programming. Solutions using these languages will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Got source code of one of those fancy voice changer apps. Instead of changing voice, i amplify the sound. I am yet to hear anyone complain, second day now.